# How to test web page has scrolling disabled with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollbar, cypress, react-modal

Maybe it's an easy one, but my `Cypress` tests fail to test locked scrolling functionality.

So I have this `React` modal component which sets `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` upon mount (client side only)

I have the following `Cypress`'s test suite:

```
  it('page cant scroll when modal is open', () => {
    cy.get('[data-testid="button"]')
      .first()
      .click();

    cy.window().scrollTo('bottom');
    
    // scroll should be disabled
    cy.window()
      .its('scrollY')
      .should('equal', 0);

    // cy.get('[data-testid="modal"]')
    //   .scrollTo('bottom')
    //   .its('scrollY')
    //   .should('not.equal', 0);
  });
```

`Error message: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected 802 to equal 0`

Looks like Cypress is able to scroll the `window` even though this not possible when manually scrolling the page.

Any idea what the issue could be?

OP's edit: Scrolling the page programmatically still works (`window.scrollTo()`). The `overflow` property hides the scrollbar but this doesn't mean the scroll functionality is actually blocked (beyond a simple user interaction)

I was advised to use another approach for testing the scroll freeze through `pagedown` and `pageup` key navigation. Using the mentioned keys will be blocked on the actual page and user won't be able to scroll.

```
  it('page cant scroll when modal is open', () => {
    cy.get('[data-testid="button"]')
      .first()
      .click();

    cy.get('body').type('{pagedown}');

    cy.window()
      .its('scrollY')
      .should('equal', 0);

    cy.get('[data-testid="overlay"]').click();

    cy.get('body').type('{pagedown}');

    cy.window()
      .its('scrollY')
      .should('not.equal', 0);
  });
```

As with the previous code example, it makes sense for this snippet to throw error as well. `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected 46 to equal 0`.

Comment: So when the modal opens users see a blocked scrolling behavior. Then why do you test the scrolling behavior? When you are writing your cypress tests you need to test what users see.

Comment: @hurricane, because you test whether the logic you've implemented works correctly, no?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that testing that `expect($el.document.body.style.overflow).to.eq('hidden')` is not very useful because you already know that to be the case. You say

> I have this React modal component which sets `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` upon mount

Are you testing the React Modal component or how it interacts with the app?

---

Taking a look at the [Material-UI Modal](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/#simple-modal) (Simple Modal demo), when I click on the "Open Modal" button it applies the same style to `body`

```html
<body dir="ltr" style="padding-right: 16px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Visually the scrollbar has gone when the modal is open.

The best approach I found was to measure widths before and after opening the modal. The scrollbar is actually attached to the `html` element, so this is what I measured (relative to the window)

```js
cy.visit('https://material-ui.com/components/modal/');

cy.window().then(win => {
  const htmlWidth = Cypress.$('html')[0].scrollWidth;
  const scrollBarWidth = win.innerWidth - htmlWidth;
  expect(scrollBarWidth).to.be.gt(0);                 // scrollbar is present
})

cy.contains('button', 'Open Modal').click();          // open the modal

cy.window().then(win => {
  const htmlWidth = Cypress.$('html')[0].scrollWidth;
  const scrollBarWidth = win.innerWidth - htmlWidth;
  expect(scrollBarWidth).to.be.eq(0);                 // scrollbar is absent
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! A page width seems like quite a reasonable measurment to test in this case!

Comment: Hey, just to mention that the test won't work on local Mac due to the automatic scroll bar behaviour based on mouse or trackpad. In other words the scroll bar is shown only upon user interaction, Cypress can't detect its width.

Comment: You can probably overcome that by applying `.focus()` - "upon user interaction" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a scroll behavior on a web page by setting the `overflow` property to `hidden` like so `window.document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'`.

Assuming the `React` modal component sets `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` as you mentioned previously.

You could assert that `scrolling` is not enabled with `one-liner` like so:

```
cy.window().then(($el) => expect($el.document.body.style.overflow).to.eq('hidden'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Althought changing the overflow style from visible to hiden is what my Modal component does, it didn't corss my mind to test against this. I kept on insiting to prove the scroll y offset would equal 0.

Comment: Looks like `window.scrollTo()` works smoothly even if `overflow:hidden` is set. It wouldn't work though if both the html and body elements have styles updated to `{overflow:hidden, height: 100%}` which isn't most pleasant solution imo.

Comment: @pollx happy to help, does my solution works for you? It wasn't clear to me in your comment. I agree this is not the most pleasant solution. It doesn't come to mind another solution at the moment. Maybe you can abstract this `one-liner` in a custom command? So you don't litter your code base with it? I'll post another answer if I think another solution

Comment: your solution works good for my case, thank you!

Comment: Awesome, so my next suggestion will be to add it as a custom command so you can abstract this assertion. Name it `cy.isWindowScrollable()` or something along those lines. If my solution helps you, I'll appreciate it if you accept & upvote my answer!